# How to handle "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException" exception in the Springboot

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot application and exposed an Endpoint to fetch OrderDetails based on OrderId.

But, We are getting an ***Intermittent*** `"class org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException"` exception.

I am not able to figure out what is going wrong.
Any help on this would be of great help. Any suggestions to understand the error and troubleshooting method would help me learn it better.

**Method Signature**

```
 @Override
    @Transactional
    public Optional<OrderResponse> getOrder(String orderId) {
        // logic to fetch data using JPA and Entities
    }
```

**Error:**

```
com.temp.services.exception.tempSystemException: class org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException","params":"null","result":"{
  "errorMessage": "class org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException",
  "causedBy": "BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext",
  "methodSignature": "Optional com.ros.cms.services.adapters.OrderService.getOrder(String)",
  "methodParameters": "[\"1234567\"]"
}","payload":"null"}
```

**Stack Trace is as follows:**

```
Failed to invoke com.test.services.adapters.DefaultOrderService@39274073. (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:170)
  org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1059)
  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:227)
  org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.getMetamodels(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:85)
  org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:56)
  org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:26)
  org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractFactoryBean.java:134)
  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1631)
  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)
  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolvePreparedArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:786)
  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:123)
  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1137)
  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1028)
  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
  org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ObjectFactoryCreatingFactoryBean$TargetBeanObjectFactory.getObject(ObjectFactoryCreatingFactoryBean.java:148)
  org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener.touchForUpdate(AuditingEntityListener.java:96)
  sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10756.invoke(null:-1)
  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.ListenerCallback.performCallback(ListenerCallback.java:49)
  org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.CallbackRegistryImpl.callback(CallbackRegistryImpl.java:112)
  org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.CallbackRegistryImpl.preUpdate(CallbackRegistryImpl.java:76)
  org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaFlushEntityEventListener.invokeInterceptor(JpaFlushEntityEventListener.java:68)
  org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.handleInterception(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:342)
  org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.scheduleUpdate(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:293)
  org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:160)
  org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:231)
  org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:102)
  org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:61)
  org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1227)
  org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1293)
  org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
  org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
  org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
  org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:110)
  org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:74)
  org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:99)
  org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:90)
  org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:415)
  org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:393)
  org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
  org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:506)
  org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
  org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
  org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
  org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
  org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
  org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
  org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
  org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
  org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
  org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
  org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
  org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
  com.sun.proxy.$Proxy808.getItemlookup(null:-1)
  com.abc.services.adapters.DefaultOrderService.getOrder(DefaultOrderService.java:136)
  sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10790.invoke(null:-1)
  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
  org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
  org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
  org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:58)
  org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
  org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
  org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
  org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterAdvice.java:43)
  org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
  org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
  org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
  org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
  org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
  org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
  org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
  org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
  com.sun.proxy.$Proxy811.getOrder(null:-1)
  sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10789.invoke(null:-1)
  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  org.mule.processor.InvokerMessageProcessor.process(InvokerMessageProcessor.java:167)
  org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
  org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111)
```

**POM.XML**

```
  <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-oracle</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.security.test.version}</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**Default Service Class:**

```
@Override 
    @Transactional
    public Optional<OrderResponse> getOrder(String orderId) {
        try {       

       Optional<OrderEntity> order =orderRepository.getByOrderNo(orderId);      
        if(order.isPresent()) 
        {
            List<OrderItemEntity> items = orderItemRepository.findByIdOrderNo(orderId);

           for(OrderItemEntity i:items) {

                List<ItemSupplierEntity> itemSupp =  itemSupplierRepository
                        .getItemlookup(order.get().getOrderNo(), i.getId().getItem(),
                                order.get().getSupplier().getId());


                ItemSupplierEntity itemExp = (ItemSupplierEntity) itemSupplierRepository
                        .getExpDetail(i.getId().getItem(),
                                Long.valueOf(order.get().getSupplier().getId()));

                if (null != itemSupp && null != itemExp) {
                    itemSupp.stream().forEach(sup->{
                        sup.setLoad(itemExp.getLoad());
                        sup.setCommission(itemExp.getCommission());
                        sup.setRoyalty(itemExp.getRoyalty());
                        sup.setFreight(itemExp.getFreight());
                        sup.setDuty(itemExp.getDuty());
                });
                }

                i.getItemmaster().setItemSuppList(itemSupp);
                Optional<ItemMasterEntity> optItemMaster =null;
                if(null != i.getId() && null != i.getId().getItem()) {
                     optItemMaster = itemMasterRepo.getSizeGroup(i.getId().getItem());
                }

                logger.info("optItemMaster : "+optItemMaster);
                if(null != optItemMaster &&  optItemMaster.isPresent()) {
                    ItemMasterEntity itemMaster = optItemMaster.get();
                    logger.info("itemMaster "+itemMaster.toString());
                    i.getItemmaster().setSizeGroup(itemMaster.getSizeGroup());
                    i.getItemmaster().setSizeGroupDesc(itemMaster.getSizeGroupDesc());
                }

                List<PackItemEntity> packItemList = i.getItemmaster().getPackItemList();
                if(!packItemList.isEmpty()) {
               logger.info("Iterating through each component if this is a pack");
                    for (PackItemEntity comp : packItemList) {
                    logger.info("Getting ComponentItem's SizeGroup");
                    if(itemMasterRepo.getSizeGroup(comp.getId().getItem()).isPresent()) {
                   Optional<ItemMasterEntity> compIme = itemMasterRepo.getSizeGroup(comp.getId().getItem());
                        comp.getItemmaster().setSizeGroup(compIme.get().getSizeGroup());
                        comp.getItemmaster().setSizeGroupDesc(compIme.get().getSizeGroupDesc());
                    }
                }
            }
            }
            order.get().setItems(items);            

            OrderResponse  orderResp = orderRepository.wrap(order.get());
            for(int i = 0; i < orderResp.getItems().size(); i++) {
                OrderItemResponse orderItemResp = orderResp.getItems().get(i);
                orderItemResp.setRecNo(String.valueOf(i+1));
                if(null!=orderItemResp && orderItemResp.getComp()) {                    
                    List<ItemSuppCountryLocEntity> ordloc = itemSuppCountryLocRepo.getItemHtsDetails(orderResp.getOrderNo(), orderItemResp.getPackNo());
                    if(null != ordloc && !ordloc.isEmpty()) {
                        ItemLocId itemLocId = new ItemLocId();
                        itemLocId.setItem(orderItemResp.getItem());
                        itemLocId.setLoc(ordloc.stream().findFirst().get().getItemSuppCountryLocId().getLocation());
                        ItemLocEntity itemLoc = itemLocRepo.findOne(itemLocId);
                        if(null != itemLoc)
                            orderItemResp.setRetail(itemLoc.getRetail());
                    }
                }
            }
            Optional<OrderResponse> orderResponse = Optional.of(orderResp);
            return orderResponse;
        }
        }catch(org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException e) {
            if ( this.appContext.getParent() != null) {
                this.appContext.getParent().getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
            }else {      
                this.appContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
            }

        }

            return Optional.empty();       
    }
```

Comment: When does this happend?

Comment: Can you share your entire OrderService class as well as the class having Spring Boot Configuration

Comment: please push your project to GitHub to be able to very all your application context. It will be the easy way to be abe to give it a try.

Comment: This is an Intermittent issue. We don't get it frequently